# SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) - пусто

Tags: php, xml

Получаю массив из xml путём `simplexml_load_file`
Всё работает отлично, записываю массив в сессию (сессии заведомо работают нормально проверено на статических переменных).
При выводе сессии в своей странице - `print $_SESSION['text_for_speach'][5]`, она срабатывает, значит массив там присутствует. Но стоит передать сессию на другую страницу, как происходит пустота.
Если посмотреть на пустоту через `print_r ($_SESSION['text_for_speach'][5]);`то получается вот это:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)
```

Почему так происходит? Почему обычная (созданная вручную) переменная проходит, а этот массив не передаётся? В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось массив нужно собирать через `urlencode` и `htmlentities`

```
$text_for_speach[$sufix]=htmlentities(urlencode($full_text));
```

Всё заработало!